# node, how do I kill/stop node process? Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to kill node process but always get error.

```
ps aux | grep node

root     21960  0.0  0.0  16976   972 pts/3    S+   00:58   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

when I tried to kill using -9 and even -2 I get this-bash: kill: (21960) - No such process

```
 kill -9 21960
-bash: kill: (21960) - No such process

 kill -2 21960
 -bash: kill: (21960) - No such process

 kill -9 16976
 -bash: kill: (16976) - No such process

 kill -2 16976
 -bash: kill: (16976) - No such process
```

Comment: That PID is the `grep` process, not `node`. It's done by the time it finishes printing.

Comment: Isn't node usually run through the `npm` command?

Comment: I usually use `killall node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the PID you are receiving is from the grep process by the returned value

```
grep --color=auto node
```

You can always use pidof to get your node pids

```
pidof node
```

Or you could just kill all of the node pids outright

```
pkill node
```

But based on the returned value of your ps aux, it doesn't look like a node process is running.